# Using matplotlib's colormap for bokeh's color bar

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, bokeh

I want to create a bokeh [ColorBar](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#color-bars) using matplotlib's coolwarm colormap. Ticks are not necessary.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key here is to get a valid palette for matplotlib's coolwarm colormap. `bokeh.palette` module has only four matplotlib palettes, not including coolwarm. You need to make it yourself (or use `colorcet` package as explained later).

A typical big `bokeh.palette` has 256 colors in a list of (hex) RGB color strings. A general idea is to sample 256 colors from matplotlib coolwarm colormap and covert them into a list of (hex) RGB color strings. Instantiate the coolwarm class with a list of numbers will return a list of RGBA colors. RGB values for each color are within [0, 1] and A=1.0. bokeh.colors.RGB requires input RGBA one at a time with RGBA being independent int arguments within [0, 255].

```
from bokeh.colors import RGB
from matplotlib import cm

m_coolwarm_rgb = (255 * cm.coolwarm(range(256))).astype('int')
coolwarm_palette = [RGB(*tuple(rgb)).to_hex() for rgb in m_coolwarm_rgb]
```

You can now use `coolwarm_palette` as a `palette` (replacing "Viridis256") in line:

```
color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", low=1, high=1e7)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`colorcet` package](https://bokeh.github.io/colorcet/) if that is a viable option for you. `colorcet.coolwarm` is the `palette` to use here. However, as you might see after trying them yourself, the final plots are slightly different in color distribution due to differences in color sampling.